# how to get android firmware version installed in phone?

Tags: android

while developing an application how to get current operating system version installed in mobile phone?

for example,

1.5,2.1 etc..

can any one guide me how to get it?

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [android.os.Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html). SDK or SDK in contain the API version. android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES contains the relevant constants.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String deviceSoftwareVersion = telephonyManager.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();
```